# Perl: Search a pdf file recursivley in a large directory structure

Tags: perl, search, perl-module

I am new to Perl.
I want to recursively search a `pdf` file in a large directory tree containing multiple sub-folders,sub-sub folders and a huge amount of files.
I am using `File::Find::Rule` to achieve this. But, the performance impact is huge. 
The script is taking a huge amount of time to search.

Snippet from my Perl script:

```
@folders = File::Find::Rule -> file -> name('*.[pP][dD][fF]') -> in($folderPath);
```

Is there any other way to achieve this without impacting performance?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How does the (non-perl) command `find start_dir -name "*.[pP][dD][fF]"`compare? Is that waaaay faster than your Perl script?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is simple: Instead of looking at each candidate file as it is encountered, you are waiting for [File::Find::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find::Rule) to build a list and return it to you. That means you will always wait until it has looked at all the files under that tree. And, from a cold start and with a sufficient number of files, that is going to take a long time before any results are shown.

Instead, you can use the underlying [File::Find](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Find) to check each file as it is encountered. You might also find [Path::Tiny's `iterator`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#iterator) useful.

You are not going to change the time required to visit every file under a tree. However, by processing each file as it is encountered, you are going to 1) reduce the memory footprint of your program as a huge list does not have to be constructed; and 2) you are going to see results faster.

Something like this will get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::HomeDir qw(my_documents);
use Path::Tiny;

my $it = path(my_documents)->iterator({ recurse => 1 });

while (my $path = $it->()) {
    return $path->is_file and $path =~ / [.] pdf \z/ix;
    do_something_with_pdf( $path );
}

sub do_something_with_pdf {
    print $_[0]->canonpath, "\n";
}
```

If you do like the *rule* part of `File::Find::Rule`, you may prefer [Path::Iterator::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Iterator::Rule). The important rule is to avoiding waiting for a potentially very large list to be constructed before starting processing.

However, if all you need is a quick way to get a list of all PDF files, you should consider using [The Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) instead:

```
my $cmd = 'ag -g "\.[pP][dD][fF]$" ' . $folderPath; 
chomp(my @files = qx/$cmd/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a subroutine which recursively searches subdirectories. In my example below you must pass your starting directory and an array (by reference, i.e.: \@name_of_array) which will be filled with the subdirectories. I hope it improves performance, but I am not sure about that

```
sub list_dirs
{
    my ($dir, $dirs) = @_;
    opendir(D, $dir) || die "cannot open directory $dir\n\n";
    my @tmp_dirs = readdir(D);
    closedir(D);
    foreach my $tmp_dir (@tmp_dirs)
    {
        if (-d "$dir/$tmp_dir")
        {
            next if ($tmp_dir eq "..");
            next if ($tmp_dir eq ".");
            push @$dirs, "$dir/$tmp_dir";
            list_dirs("$dir/$tmp_dir", $dirs);
        }
    }
    return $dirs;
}
```